# JPA FBSQLException The resultSet is closed

Tags: hibernate, firebird, jaybird

Having this exception during a pgination query i fix the problem with

```
((Session)this.em.getDelegate()).connection().setHoldability(ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
final Query query_ = this.em.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(indexStart);
```

But now the exception occure during the lazy loading of collection, so how to fix it again?
I think that the problem is Firebird JDBC driver is not fully support JPA

```
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: The resultSet is closed
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.getField(AbstractResultSet.java:687)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.getString(AbstractResultSet.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:593)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
    at com.agitech.erp.bean.act.ActNSCFBean.getTabs(ActNSCFBean.java:299)
```

Comment: Which jaybird version do you use? This sounds like bug that was fixed in 2.2.4 or maybe 2.2.3

Comment: v2.2.3 but i just upgrade the pom to 2.2.4 without changing DLLs (i think its not needed), but the exception still hapening

Comment: Looks like jpa assumes holdable result sets as default. I'd need to investigate. You could try the connection property defaultHoldableResultSet=true in the connection string

Comment: sorry but, already tested with ?defaultHoldableResultSet=true same result

Comment: Oubs, i had multiple databases, in fact adding ?defaultHoldableResultSet to the right DATABASE URL fix the ALL the problems